# Heavy TCP traffic on loopback

Tags: networking, wireshark, netstat, loopback

While trying to generate some test traffic on my loopback interface, I noticed there was so much noise there that the output from Wireshark was essentially useless, with tons of SYN/RST, ACK packets on port 4101 (which some Googling suggests has to do with braille services? I'm not aware that I'm running anything remotely related to that, but, then agan, this is Ubuntu we're talking about).

```
ggoncalves@inspiron:~$ sudo netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4776/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2626/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11501/cupsd         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53127           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6789/transmission-g 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2626/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2625/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      11501/cupsd         
tcp6       0      0 :::53127                :::*                    LISTEN      6789/transmission-g 
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      2626/systemd-resolv 
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      2625/sshd           
ggoncalves@inspiron:~$
```

[Wireshark output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cEQV.png)

Is this normal? Why wouldn't this service show up on netstat? This traffic looks absolutely useless, so I'd like to disable it if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SYN/RST indicates that the port is closed so then the application closes the connection which means that it would be visible in netstat during only a fraction of a second.

You can try to drop the SYN of this traffic with the following iptable rule:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo0 -p tcp --dport 4101 -j DROP
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -i lo0 -p tcp --dport 4101 -j DROP
```

You should then be able to see with netstat which application is generating this traffic as it will stay in the "SYN sent" state during a while.

Answer (score 2):

Reason for such noise in loopback interface in my case (ubuntu 16.10) was xbrlapi.

You can identify the software by letting it to have something to connect to: e.g. nc -l 4101. After that the netstat -atulpn shows you what process is connected to the nc on which source port.